# Using the first column for variable names and vice versa with reshape

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

I have a DF as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DF <- structure(list(fullname = c(" Returns Count", " Dependent Exemptions Count", 
" Joint Returns Count", " Single Returns Count", " Head of Household Count"
), year = c(1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998), State = c("Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"), Total_Returns = c(1879778, 
1354776, 774623, 690246, 382183), Breakeven_Loss = c(11649, 4254, 
5365, 5075, 591)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want switch the first column with the row names, keeping the state and year in place. I tried multiple things, among others:

```
valvar <- names(DF)[4:16]
DF<- dcast(DF, year + State ~ fullname, value.var= valvar)
```

or

```
valvar <- names(DF)[4:16]
DF<- dcast(DF, year + State + valvar ~ fullname)
```

But neither work. What am I missing here?

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to melt first:

```
library(data.table)
DF[, melt(.SD, id.vars = c("year", "State", "fullname"))
   ][, dcast(.SD, variable + year + State ~ fullname)]

         variable year   State  Dependent Exemptions Count  Head of Household Count  Joint Returns Count  Returns Count  Single Returns Count
1:  Total_Returns 1998 Alabama                     1354776                   382183               774623        1879778                690246
2: Breakeven_Loss 1998 Alabama                        4254                      591                 5365          11649                  5075
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have noticed that I am still running into trouble, because I have NA's in the value column leading to the function defaulting to length. Is there any easy fix for this (apart from removing the NA's)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. If removing the NA's works, than that would be the best fix, I guess.

Comment: Well, I would prefer not to remove anything from the data, as the unavailability of the data is informative by itself. Also I would like to leave the data as intact as possible, also for reproduction by others.

Comment: There was a state in the dataset twice.. That was the problem.. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Get the data in long format first and then in wide again changing the column name.

```
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Total_Returns, Breakeven_Loss)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = fullname, values_from = value)


# A tibble: 2 x 8
#   year State  name       ` Returns Count` ` Dependent Exemptions… ` Joint Returns Co… ` Single Returns C… ` Head of Household…
#  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                 <dbl>                   <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>                <dbl>
#1  1998 Alaba… Total_Ret…          1879778                 1354776              774623              690246               382183
#2  1998 Alaba… Breakeven…            11649                    4254                5365                5075                  591
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I suggest `cols = -c(year, State, fullname)` instead of `cols = c(Total_Returns, Breakeven_Loss)` ? My actual data (and I suspect maybe the data of others who would use this) has much more variables than the example I gave.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain to me what happens when I suppress the warning like suggested here? `Warning message:
Values in value are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use values_fn = list(value = list)` to suppress this warning.`

Comment: If you get that warning means your data does not have a unique identifier column to pivot on. In such case you can select only relevant columns and use `DF %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(year, State, fullname)) %>%
  group_by(year, state, name) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = fullname, values_from = value)`

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, a couple of NA's are the cause of this. If I use the solution from your comment I get the error: `Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context`.

Comment: I guess there is some bracket that is missing or incomplete which is why you get the error. Although this works for the sample data shared I think you have too many other columns which might give you the first warning. `select` only relevant columns before reshaping.

Comment: There was a state in the dataset twice.. That was the problem.. Thank you for your help!